# Applying criteria from one SELECT DISTINCT data column, to match a second data column of examples

Tags: sql-server, join, select

I am working with a set of vehicle data, all in the same table, that uses the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.VIN_NUM AS [Registration VIN]
    ,DISTINCT STUFF(SUBSTRING(a.VIN_NUM, 1, 10),9,1,'_') AS [VIN STRING] 
FROM
    dbo.DMV_All_Tests AS a
WHERE
    KeyDateTime between '2017/12/01' and '2018/11/30' AND
    INSP_TEST_TYPE = 'B' AND
    INSP_ATTEMPT_NUM = '1' AND
    EPA_VEHICLE_TYPE = 'HDV' 
ORDER BY
    [VIN STRING] DESC
```

The query pulls from a table a vehicle VIN (VIN_NUM) and its primary code identificiation, the VIN STRING. So for instance, 1ABCD23EF4G567890 becomes 1ABCD23_F. The DISTINCT is to identify each unique VIN STRING combination in the table's yearlong data set (it comes out to ~30k members).

My goal is to pull an example of a VIN NUM to match each distinct VIN STRING. Each row in the queried result would have two columns/members - the VIN STRING (1ABCD23_F), and the next column in the row would give an example VIN_NUM from the table for the VIN STRING (1ABCD23EF4G567890).

I'm thinking this would be a SELECT TOP ONE to just pull the first instance of the VIN NUM, but I'm not certain how it would be structured to supply that criteria-matching VIN NUM to accompany each VIN STRING. Would it involve an INNER JOIN?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      Max(a.VIN_NUM) AS [Registration VIN]
    , STUFF(SUBSTRING(a.VIN_NUM, 1, 10),9,1,'_') AS [VIN STRING] 
FROM
     dbo.DMV_All_Tests AS a
WHERE
    KeyDateTime between '2017/12/01' and '2018/11/30' AND
    INSP_TEST_TYPE = 'B' AND
    INSP_ATTEMPT_NUM = '1' AND
    EPA_VEHICLE_TYPE = 'HDV' 
GROUP BY
    STUFF(SUBSTRING(a.VIN_NUM, 1, 10),9,1,'_')
ORDER BY
    [VIN STRING] DESC
```